# Java Game - unknown error

Tags: java

I have an error it everytime I try to start it, it comes up with a blank window and these error messages.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red Green
    at java.awt.Color.testColorValueRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.tutorial.main.HUD.render(HUD.java:32)
    at com.tutorial.main.Game.render(Game.java:118)
    at com.tutorial.main.Game.run(Game.java:85)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have a suspicion it is something to do with rendering but not sure can someone help.

I have inserted the following codes:

- Game
- Window
- SmartEnemy
- HUD
- ID
- Handler

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7580815534084638412L;

  public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

  private Thread thread;
  private boolean running = true;


  private Random r;
  private Handler handler;
  private HUD hud;
  private Spawn spawner;


  public Game() {
    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!", this);

    handler = new Handler();
    hud = new HUD();
    spawner = new Spawn(handler, hud);



    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));


    r = new Random();

    //  for(int i = 0; i <1; i++){

    //implementing Player1
    handler.addObject(new Player(WIDTH / 2 - 32, HEIGHT / 2 - 32, ID.Player, handler));
    handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH), r.nextInt(Game.HEIGHT), ID.BasicEnemy, handler));

    //implementing Player2
    //handler.addObject(new Player(WIDTH/2-32, HEIGHT/2+64, ID.Player2));   
    /*for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            //implementing BasicEnemy
                handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(WIDTH), r.nextInt(HEIGHT), ID.BasicEnemy, handler)); 
            }*/

  }

  public synchronized void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
  }

  public synchronized void stop() {
    try {
      thread.join();
      running = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    this.requestFocus();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while (running) {
      long now = System.nanoTime();
      delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
      lastTime = now;
      while (delta >= 1) {
        tick();
        delta--;
      }
      if (running) {
        render();
        frames++;

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
          timer += 1000;
          //System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
          frames = 0;
        }
      }

    }
  }

  private void tick() {
    handler.tick();
    hud.tick();
    spawner.tick();
  }

  private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
      this.createBufferStrategy(3);
      return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);


    handler.render(g);
    hud.render(g);


    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
  }


  public static float clamp(float
    var, float min, float max) {
    if (var >= max) {
      return var = max;

    } else if (var <= min) {
      return var = min;
    } else {
      return var;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();
  }
}
```

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Window extends Canvas {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -240840600533728354L;

  public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class SmartEnemy extends GameObject{

    private Handler handler;
    private GameObject player;

    public SmartEnemy(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            if(handler.object.get(i).getId() == ID.Player) player = handler.object.get(i);
        }


    }


    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 32, 32);
    }

    public void tick() {
        handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y,ID.Trail, Color.GREEN, 16, 16, 0.02f, handler));

        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        float diffX = x - player.getX() - 8;
        float diffY = y - player.getY() - 8;
        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt((x - player.getX()) * (x - player.getX()) + (y - player.getY()) * (y - player.getY()));

        velX = (float) ((-1.0/distance) * diffX);
        velY = (float) ((-1.0/distance) * diffY);

        if (y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 37) velY *= -1;
        if (x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 16) velX*= -1;


    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 16, 16);

    }

}
```

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Handler {


  LinkedList < GameObject > object = new LinkedList < GameObject > ();

  public void tick() {
    for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
      GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
      tempObject.tick();
    }
  };
  public void render(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
      GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

      tempObject.render(g);
    }

  }

  public void addObject(GameObject object) {
    this.object.add(object);
  }

  public void removeObject(GameObject object) {
    this.object.remove(object);
  }
}
```

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HUD {

    public static float HEALTH = 100;

    private float greenValue = 255;


    private int level = 1;
    private float score = 0;

    public void tick(){
        HEALTH = Game.clamp(HEALTH, 0, 100);



        greenValue = Game.clamp(greenValue, 0, 255);
        greenValue = HEALTH*2;


        score++;
    }
    public void render(Graphics g){
        //Background for Health bar
        g.setColor(Color.gray);
        g.fillRect(15, 15, 200, 32);
        //Health Bar
        g.setColor(new Color(75, (float) greenValue, 0));
        g.fillRect(15, 15, (int) (HEALTH * 2), 32);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(15, 15, 200, 32);

        g.drawString("Score: " + score, 15, 60);
        g.drawString("Level: " + level, 15, 75);
    }
    /*int level = 1, point = 0;
    //point scoring system
    for(int i = 2; i > 1; i++){
        if(HEALTH > 0){
            point++;
            System.out.println(point);
            }
        }
    }*/



    private void score(float score){
        this.score = score;
    }


    public float getScore(){
        return score;
    }


    public int getLevel(){
        return level;
    }


    public void setLevel(int level){
        this.level = level;
    }
}
```

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class GameObject {

    protected float x, y;
    protected ID id;
    protected float velX, velY;


    public GameObject(float x, float y, ID id){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;

    }



    public abstract void tick();


    public abstract void render(Graphics g);


    public abstract Rectangle getBounds();
    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return (int) x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return (int) y;
    }

    public void setId(ID id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ID getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setVelX(int velX){
        this.velX = velX;
    }

    public void setVelY(int velY){
        this.velY = velY;
    }

    public float getVelX(){
        return velX;
    }

    public float getVelY(){
        return velY;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is line 32 in HUD?

Comment: Exception says `Color parameter outside of expected range: Red Green ...at com.tutorial.main.HUD.render(HUD.java:32) ` so the problem might be in this line `g.setColor(new Color(75, (float) greenValue, 0));`

Answer (score 1):

The excetion is caused by this constructor call:

```
 new Color(75, (float) greenValue, 0)
```

You use the [`Color(float, float, float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-float-float-float-), since the second parameter has type `float`. As documented in the javadocs, this constructor takes 3 `float`s that represent rgb components. Ranges are from `0.0f` to `1.0f`, not from `0` to `255`, which is why you get the error (`75` is too large).

It seems like you should not cast the second parameter to make that statement use the `Color(int, int, int)` constructor.